# Access to object nested object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I can't access to variable object in my object, I can access to 'start', 'end' and 'category' without problem, but I dont know like access to variable Object.
I am developing an app web with Angular(no AngularJS).

This object is obtained for ...

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
<md-slider
    ngModel
    required
    #k="ngModel"
    [name]="k"
    [disabled]="false"
    [invert]="invert"
    [max]="10"
    [min]="3"
    [step]="1"
    [thumb-label]="true"
    [ngModel]="value"
    [vertical]="vertical">
</md-slider>
</form>
```

and k is setted in `ngInit`, but my problem is really access to this 'object'.

```
Object {start: "2011-01-01", end: "2017-06-27", [object Object]: 5, category: ""}
```

Thanks!!!

**RE-EDIT**
In this function I access my JSON.

```
getBestSeller(filter: JSON) {
    const k = filter['k'];
    console.log("object -> ", filter['object']) //ERROR, 'object' undefined
    //...
}
```

Comment: Show the code that gets the object into the component, and the code you're using to try to access the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
var obj =  {start: "2011-01-01", end: "2017-06-27", [object Object]: 5, category: ""}

for (var prop in obj) { 

      console.log(prop==='[object Object]' && obj[prop]); //will give [object object] value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library. You can use function `_.find()` and you get a lot of other easy access JS option what you know from other programming languages.